# jdbc driver not found again using terminal

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, terminal

I am trying to use MySQL in Java. I entered this in Terminal.

```
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java.jar
```

and my application ran smoothly, but after restarting Ubuntu. It starts asking for driver.

```
ClassNotFoundException is generated
```

Comment: what happens when you grep for mysql ? Can you run mysql from terminal/command line ?

Comment: It's understandable, because you only export the environment variable for that session. To make it persistent, you may refer the guide here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#Session-wide_environment_variables

Comment: I am not able to understand the link mentioned above.. Yes I can use mysql from the terminal